# Golang struct construction generality

Tags: go

I have a struct that two other objects implement. In this case, typeA and B repo's. There's some initialization code, which are represented as ellipses here. The initialization code is completely duplicated between both constructors, and isn't a big deal while I only have two `dbRepo`'s, but as I create more I will worry a bit more about the bad practice. Is there any way to generalize this with an interface?

```
type dbRepo struct {
    foo string
    bar string
}

type typeARepo dbRepo
type typeBRepo dbRepo

func newTypeARepo(foo, bar string) {
    ...
}

func newTypeBRepo(foo, bar string) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your code example does not look like something one would do in go. But just to be sure, could you develop a bit about your use case? For example, why two subtypes of dbRepo?

Comment: How or where is the decision to construct a type A or B made?

Comment: There are two subtypes because they each have different functions that will be called on them, based on the type of repo that they are. For example, making a call to a user database instead of an item database. I will have different queries and functions I'm looking to do based on the repository. The creation and assignment is done in a main function elsewhere. All of this is loosely following Clean architecture in Go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The practice I've personally observed in Go (and it's also what's recommended in the effective Go or getting started with Go tutorials) is just to define a `NewdbRepo` function and use it for all instantation. It's implementation would look something like;

```
func NewdbRepo(f, b string) *dbRepo {
    return &dbRepo{ foo:f, bar:b}
}
```

You can't actually define a constructor as you do in most C like languages so you just gotta provide a package scoped method to do construction for you. Also, if you're not using composite literals (the initilization style I use in my NewdbRepo implementation) then you may find that alone concise enough for your needs.

Comment: I recognize that you can't have constructors in the traditional sense of the word, but a function that builds and then returns a struct seems like a pretty constructor like function to me! I digress! I was able to do this and then use type assertion in the `NewTypeARepo()` func to achieve the desired result.

Comment: A factory function like this is not a  constructor. It is a factory function (just like you have in any other languages). A constructor requires you to call it, thus protecting you from allocating an uninitiated (erroneous) zero value structure. What more the  "dbRepo" part of the literal  "NewdbRepo" is not explicitly linked to the type "dbRepo". If you were to use some automatic refactoring tools to rename "dbRepo" to "databaseRepo", they would have no way of knowing that "NewdbRepo" needs to be refactored as well. This can be very problematic when refactoring a large project.

Comment: @eshalev if you read the answer it quite clearly explains all of this. There are no constructors in Go as stated "You can't actually define a constructor as you do in most C like languages so you just gotta provide a package scoped method to do construction for you" and also as stated, this pattern is what is presented in documentation regarding the language. And no, a constructor does not 'require you to call it' that is a rule of a language and has nothing to do with 'constructors' which are a far more loosely defined concept and behave differently from one language to the next.

Comment: Take C# as an example, for one you're not required to define a constructor in order to use the `new` keyword to instantiate a type. For two, you're able to use 'static initialization' to create an instance without calling any constructor. Those patterns are in fact far more common in OO languages than a strict requirement to define and call a constructor which honestly is pretty useless in modern development as evidenced by the complete omission of the feature from Go.

Comment: It is not about requiring the lib author to *define* a constructor.  It is about requiring a library user to *use* a constructor: Imagine you are using a cool new library. You want to construct a new Cow object. In c#, you immediately know if & how to initialize it. In fact your IDE will suggest it to you automatically. The compiler will catch you if you don't. In Go, not only will the compiler not catch you, you will also have no way to figure out what you need to call except for reading the docs. If you don't, you will only catch your error at run time.

Comment: @eshalev - yeah it's that none of that is true. The caller is not required to use a constructor because the language provides alternate ways of instantiating an object, like static initialization which I mentioned in the comment above. This problem is compounded by the fact that there is no requirement to write a constructor and if you do, it doesn't mean it works or sets the initial state for anything. It seems like you're just looking for reasons to complain about Go but what you're describing is a developer short coming and not a problem with the language.

Answer (score 2):

You can write one function with your initializing code:

```
func newDbRepo(foo, bar string) dbRepo {
        // ...
}
```

Then you can use it with type conversion:

```
a := typeARepo(newDbRepo("foo", "bar"))
b := typeBRepo(newDbRepo("foo", "bar"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Define an unexported func on the type that does the initialization then you can create few constructors that call it, for example:

```
func (db *dbRepo) init(){
    if len(db.foo) > 0 {
        //do foo init
    }
    if len(db.bar) > 0 {
        // do bar init
    }
    // do generic init
}

func NewRepo(foo, bar string) *dbRepo {
    repo := &dbRepo{foo: foo, bar: bar}
    repo.init()
    return repo
}

func NewFooRepo(foo string) *dbRepo {
    repo := &dbRepo{foo: foo}
    repo.init()
    return repo
}
```